# time to find all matching in sequential search

Tags: algorithm, search, matching, sequential

The time needed to find one match in sequential search is 
T(n)=n 
How about finding all matching for the key in a given array and all the element in the array are unique  ?? 
T(n)=?

Comment: To any key you want to search in arrary

Comment: For ex. Key =5 and If A(1)=key this one match and if A(4)=key this is another match and if A(6)=key another match and so on

Comment: What's *your* idea of the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uniqueness constraint doesn't change the time taken, as if the element is only at the end, you're still going to have to look at every element to find it.

Finding multiple matches also doesn't change the time taken, as only going through the array once can find you all elements.

So the time taken will still be `T(n) = n`, or `O(n)`.

Though I'm not really sure how there can be multiple matches **and** uniqueness - if the elements are unique, there can only be one match.

Comment: Binary search will take `O(log n)` (or `T(n) = log n`) time (which of course assumes the array is sorted).

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I have another question if the sequential search used divide and conquer to find all matching the time will be ??

Comment: It will also be `O(n)` - dividing and conquering doesn't help here.

Comment: It will help if the array is sorted and I need to find just one match ??

Comment: Then it's just binary search.